# Geoserver Point Styling - Add values from a specific field from ALL records into label

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have data with overlapping points.  (Exact locations) such as

"name","lat","lon", "total employees"

"Amtec", "50.33","22.10", "10"

"Slivy", "50.33","22.10", "15"

As you can see some records overlap and have exact locations.  I am trying to create an SLD that can display a label for total employees with the number "25".  So I need to add up all employees for all records at that location.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that result with SLD as the renderer parses the data source one feature at a time applying all matching rules to that feature before moving on to the next feature.

You will need to make a new data source with sums of employees for matching points.